# Jira Datacenter cluster deployment in cloud with 2 replicas, Jira url not working properly. With 1 replica working fine

Tags: kubernetes, jira

We are in the process of migrating our jira datacenter cluster to cloud. Created 2 Kubernates pods using kind Deployment with 2 replicas. Jira is working fine with only with 1 replica/1 pod, but as soon as I start the jira in 2nd pod, the jira URL is hanging for some time, which should not happen as jira is up in 1st pod. Secondly after some time when jira in 2nd pod is up, the URL is going, but if I click on any of the tab its coming base location/Dashboard. If I stop jira either 1st or 2nd pod, everything working good as expected. Not sure why starting jira with 2 replicas, giving this issue. There is no errors in catlina.out or atlassian-jira.log. Ingress and service for jira deployment created properly.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Antim.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/jira-on-kubernetes/issues/3) it seems that Jira server does not support horizontal scaling.

As you might see at the bottom of the github,  atlassian release the [ASK](https://github.com/Praqma/ask) (Atlassian Software in Kubernetes) tool as open-source which will allow you horizontal scaling for Jira Data Center.

You can read more about the concept [here](https://www.eficode.com/blog/atlassian-software-kubernetes).